# What is wrong with the AnimationCurve ? The lerp duration never change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I I set the lerp to 1 or to 10 the transform is moving to the target too fast.

At the top :

```
public AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
public float duration = 10.0f;
private float t;
```

At Start()

```
void Start()
    {
        t = 0.0f;
    }
```

At Update()

```
void Update()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                var v = targetTransform.position - transform.position;
                if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
                {
                    state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                    originTransform = targetTransform;
                    timer = 0;
                    return;
                }
                t += Time.deltaTime;
                float s = t / duration;
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,
                    targetTransform.position, curve.Evaluate(s));
                break;
        }
    }
```

The curve animation in the editor :

[image: Curve animation in editor inspector]

Comment: What is the lerp that you set to 1 or 10 here? If it's too fast, why don't you set it to 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to lerp from Transform.Position to your TargetPosition. That means that everytime you move you lerp from a new starting position. This will make your object move exponantially. Try lerping from a fixed start position to a fixed end position. (Unless this is what you actually want to happen)

If I read your code correctly your duration is the exact duration in seconds that your lerp should take. So I assume that's correct, just fix the "start" position of your lerp.